Which Tomura Shigaraki quirks did New Order destroy?
So far it's being mentioned that New Order destroyed the regeneration quirk from Tomura Shigaraki. But he's seeing being hit by New Order's quirk while this was destroying all the quirks it could from Tomura Shigaraki
Is it mentioned in the manga any other quirks Tomura Shigaraki lost by New Order?

In addition to the Regeneration quirk, the only other quirk that was specifically named in chapter 333 that was destroyed was Shigaraki's Reflect quirk.

Reflect: "Tomura"'s Quirk allows him to reflect any attack he receives with the same strength. This Quirk is destroyed by New Order.
Source


